# Under what conditions does gmail group distinct replies into a single thread? How can I force separate threads?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

If I have an ad running on kijiji, and I get two responses in the same day, they are considered a single conversation, and I have to split them apart.

On occasion I send out an email newsletter using mailchimp.  ALL the responses to it are glommed into a single conversation.

I just did a test from another account, sending the same message -- same subject, twice 1 minute apart.  They ended up in separate threads.  So identical subject line in a short period of time isn't sufficient, yet the kijiji replies are distinct messages.

The next are ideas that I don't know how to test.

- If I use the address+string feature, are messages to different strings considered the same thread?  E.g If my normal gmail address is j.random.user@gmail.com and I add (How?) a

  Reply-To: j.random.user+0037

to the headers will gmail consider them to be separate threads from the original?

- Same idea, but modify the From: header instead.

To re-iterate:  Gmail *sometimes* will merge two messages from the same From: address and same subject into the same conversation thread. (Kijiji example above)  But *sometimes* will not.  (Two emails, same user, same subject.)

Use case:

I want to send out an email with a list of BCC receipients.  I want EACH reply to be it's own conversation.  How do I do that?